# UITextField change width when clicking button

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to make a search field in my app, and I was wondering if it is possible to make it invisible to begin with and then make it appear with the click of a button, like with the magnifying glass in the video below.

[image]

I have tried making the width of a UITextField 0 to begin with and then make a button make the width larger, but I am doing something wrong, and I can not figure out what. Maybe you could make an example in a blank project and show/link the code?

I hope you can help :)

Comment: Please post code which you tried.

Comment: I think the easist way is to have the text field initally being hidden by the button, and then animate it's position to the left, to make it appear. To prevent unattended events, also make it hidden/visible or at least unresponsive before the animation.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Yeah, that sounds right. Maybe you could make an example as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function for expand the SearchTextField

```
  func setTextField(setExpand:Bool = false){

        self.txtfldSearch.delegate = self
        self.txtfldSearch.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.none
        self.txtfldSearch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        let bottomLine = CALayer()
        bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
          if setExpand{
                      self.txtfldSearch.frame = CGRect(x: 
                      self.viewContainer.frame.origin.x + 8, y: 
                      self.txtfldSearch.frame.origin.y, width: 
                      (self.btnSearch.frame.origin.x - 
                      (self.viewContainer.frame.origin.x + 16)), 
                       height: self.txtfldSearch.frame.size.height)
                       bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 
                      self.txtfldSearch.frame.size.height-2, width: 
                      self.txtfldSearch.frame.size.width, height: 2.0)
            }
       else{
                    self.txtfldSearch.frame = CGRect(x: 
                    self.btnSearch.frame.origin.x - 8, 
                    y: self.txtfldSearch.frame.origin.y, width: 0, 
                    height:self.txtfldSearch.frame.size.height)
                    bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 
                    self.txtfldSearch.frame.size.height-2, width: 
                    self.txtfldSearch.frame.size.width, height: 2.0)
            }  
      }    
    self.txtfldSearch.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)

}
```

Use of Code For Expanding pass true and other case pass false

```
  self.setTextField(setExpand: true)
```

Comment: Ah, nice! I have some questions to your function though. Could you maybe show how and what you have declared? Like the textField, button and so on

Comment: @Chris  In storyboard I put UiView, UITextField and a UIButton

and make connection to viewcontroller.
    IBOutlet weak var viewContainer: UIView!
    IBOutlet weak var btnSearch: UIButton!
    IBOutlet weak var txtfldSearch: UITextField!

Comment: Ah, okay. The UIView is a view you are adding and not the original view in the view controller, right? When I try your, the bottom-line does not disappear when I use the self.setTextField(setExpand: false) function. Can you make it disappear?

Comment: Hmm, I can't see that you have changed anything?

Comment: @Chris  please create bottom view programmatically. then above code worked fine.

Comment: Maybe you could link your project on GitHub? I still can not seem to figure it out :/

Comment: @Chris Please find this https://github.com/sarveshsingh88/Sample.git

Answer (score 2):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
        //change view width
    }) { (completed) in
        //you can use completion or you can delete I am using it like that
        self.searchTextview.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```

I am using this for my view. You can change for your need. Change constraints or width with animation

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can not seem to make it work. Maybe you could modify the code to fit a textField?